# Reading from the keyboard

Tags: c#, focus, keypress

I made a complex calculator in `C#` with two textboxes and buttons. I would like to operate the calculator using only the keyboard. I put the same code in `textbox1_Keypress`, `textbox2_Keypress` and in `Form_Keypress`.

1. If the focus was in any of the textbox, the code works well but it writes the arithmetic sign in the textbox and I have to erase it manually to enter another value. How to make it not show in the textbox?
2. Although I used the same code also in `Form_keypress` but whenever I'm out of the textboxes, the code won't work.

Any suggestions about how to make the form response immediately for the keyboard at anytime and no matter where the focus was?

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            double d;

            if (flag == 1)
            {
                Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out d);
                getOperand.Real = d;
            }
            else if (flag == 2)
            {
                Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out d);
                getOperand.Magnitude = d;
            }

        }
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            double d;
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                Double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out d);
                getOperand.Imag = d;
            }
            else if (flag == 2)
            {
                Double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out d);
                getOperand.Angle = d;
            }

        }
    }

 private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

        if (e.KeyChar == '+')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 1;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '-')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 2;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '*')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 3;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '/')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 4;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '=')
        {
            operand2.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand2.Imag = getOperand.Imag;

            switch (flag1)
            {
                case 1:
                    operand1 = operand1 + operand2;
                    break;
                case 2: operand1 = operand1 - operand2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    operand1 = operand1 * operand2;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    operand1 = operand1 / operand2;
                    break;
            }
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Real.ToString());
                textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Imag.ToString());
            }
            else if (flag == 2)
            {
                textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Magnitude.ToString());
                textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Angle.ToString());
            }

            //   MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:D2}", operand1.Real.ToString()));

            //  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:D2}", operand1.Imag.ToString()));

            listBox1.Items.Add(operand1);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyChar == '+')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 1;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '-')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 2;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '*')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 3;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '/')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 4;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '=')
        {
            operand2.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand2.Imag = getOperand.Imag;

            switch (flag1)
            {
                case 1:
                    operand1 = operand1 + operand2;
                    break;
                case 2: operand1 = operand1 - operand2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    operand1 = operand1 * operand2;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    operand1 = operand1 / operand2;
                    break;
            }
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Real.ToString());
                textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Imag.ToString());
            }
            else if (flag == 2)
            {
                textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Magnitude.ToString());
                textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Angle.ToString());
            }

            //   MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:D2}", operand1.Real.ToString()));

            //  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:D2}", operand1.Imag.ToString()));

            listBox1.Items.Add(operand1);
        }

    }

    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyChar == '+')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 1;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '-')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 2;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '*')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 3;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '/')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 4;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '=')
        {
            operand2.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand2.Imag = getOperand.Imag;

            switch (flag1)
            {
                case 1:
                    operand1 = operand1 + operand2;
                    break;
                case 2: operand1 = operand1 - operand2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    operand1 = operand1 * operand2;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    operand1 = operand1 / operand2;
                    break;
            }
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Real.ToString());
                textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Imag.ToString());
            }
            else if (flag == 2)
            {
                textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Magnitude.ToString());
                textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", operand1.Angle.ToString());
            }

            //   MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:D2}", operand1.Real.ToString()));

            //  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0:D2}", operand1.Imag.ToString()));

            listBox1.Items.Add(operand1);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some relevant code (i.e. the code from the `Keypress` handlers). Have you done any research? Have you looked at the [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property?

Comment: i just added  the  code to the question

Answer (score 0):

In the KeyPress event you have to set the `Handled` property of [KeyPressEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx) to true 
to avoid the usual event handling (i.e. to avoid to append the '+' to your TextBox).

For the Form1_KeyPress method, it's not really clear what "won't work" exactly means. I suppose that what's happening is that the code is never executed. This is because the KeyPress event is always sent to one of the controls that lie on the Form (You don't have just the 2 TextBoxes, I suppose). This means that you have to register to the KeyPress event of every Control on your Form if you want the same behaviour wherever the focus is.

BTW I'd refactor the code having just one single method handling the KeyPress, checking the sender object when you need to do something slightly different depending on the Control that got the input.